# How to create a .net assembly in C#, which can be consumed by MATLAB?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, .net-assembly

I am writing a .net assembly in c# using Visual Studio 2022:

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int f(int i) { return 3 * i; }
    }
}
```

When I try to load it into MATLAB using the following script:

```
try
  NET.addAssembly(fullfile(pwd, "ClassLibrary1.dll"));
catch ex
end

ex.ExceptionObject.LoaderExceptions.Get(0).Message
```

I get the error message:

> Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" oder eine
> Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die
> angegebene Datei nicht finden.

I don't know exactly what the english wording is, something like

> Could not load file or assembly "System.Runtime....

The dll-file was locked by MATLAB after this.

I tried creating the assembly using .NET 6.0  as well as .NET core 3.1 in combination with MATLAB 2021b and 2022a, all with the same error message.
Just for .NET core, the missing assembly version was

> System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0

I also tried to consume the assembly with c# console programs, which worked without issues.

Comment: I used to do a fair amount of this MATLAB interop. Sometimes I was able to resolve load failures using the [AssemblyResolve](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads) event so I wanted to make sure you're aware of it. What would happen to me is that `MyClassLibraries` would have all its dependent assemblies in its folder, but MATLAB was executing in a different `Location` and didn't know where to probe. I did come to a place where, instead of relying on `AssemblyResolve`, I would go ahead and preload assemblies explicitly. It's about as much fun as it sounds.

Comment: Your issue "might/might not" have to do with that.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this exception and in English, Matlab says this: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: By the way, @MiB_Coder, what is the output of `NET.addAssembly('System.Runtime');` `char(System.Environment.Version.ToString())`? On my Matlab 2020b installation it is `'4.0.30319.42000'`. I recompiled the assembly using NetStandard2.0 and it worked. I think the question here is not 'how to create an assembly...', but how to get Matlab to use a newer version of System.Runtime.

Comment: I think what @dmedine just said makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @IVSoftware Would I have to do the AssembyResolve thing on the C# or MATLAB side?

Comment: Did you get a chance to check the return value like dmedine suggested? In addition to running that command, what is the true/false value of `NET.isNETSupported` as documented [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/net.isnetsupported.html). It sounds _very_ plausible that MATLAB needs an older framework version and you should target your `ClassLibrary1` to build on NetStandard2.0 build and see if it works. If .NET core 3.1 is in fact too new, your assembly won't be able to get far enough in the load for `AssemblyResolve` to work such is the catastrophic nature of it.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio 2019 around it still has a Class Library template for NetStandard2.0 you should try that, dmedine likely hit the nail on the head. I see no support for .NET core 3 in [System Requirements for Using MATLAB Interface to .NET](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/system-requirements-for-using-matlab-interface-to-net.html#:~:text=The%20MATLAB%20interface%20requires%20the,on%20Framework%202.0%20and%20above.).

Comment: If I recall correctly, you have to install older .net sdks in order to use older versions in visual studio.

Comment: What is weird, though, is that according to the output of `>> dotnet --info` I don't have v4 installed anywhere. I have .net runtimes 2.1.30, 3.1.3, 3.1.22, 5.0.13, 5.0.16, and 6.0.1. I also tried adding the line `<supportedRuntime version="v6.0"/>` to matlab.exe.config, but it had no effect on the output I reported above.

Comment: @dmedine: The output of "NET.addAssembly('System.Runtime'); char(System.Environment.Version.ToString())" is the same as yours:
'4.0.30319.42000'

Comment: @IVSoftware: NET.isSupported gives "1"

Comment: @dmedine: Compiling with vs2019 with .NET Standard 2.0 works on my side as well.

Comment: @MiB_Coder glad to know it works. Hopefully you won't need any of the language features available in newer versions and this can work. Since your version is the same as mine, I suspect that Mathworks hasn't updated Matlab with support for newer versions of .NET, which is a pity. C# has become a very, very powerful programming language since Standard 2.0.

Comment: @dmedine have you considered consolidating your comments to a regular Answer? You resolved the OPs issue by identifying that **.NET core 3.1** is too new and **NetStandard2.0** works when neither seems very obvious looking at the MATLAB docs. That plus a build using **Visual Studio 2019** seems to be the recipe. My upvoting finger would view such a post as _useful_ for providing a snapshot of what works with MATLAB "today" for others who may find themselves in the same boat. Just an idea...

Comment: I agreee, Thanks to @dmedine for providing a solution.

Comment: @IVSoftware, yes. I wanted to do a bit more research and roll the comments into an answer. Specifically, I would like to know what Matlab truly offers in terms of .NET runtime. Apparently it is 4.0.30319.42000, but it would be good to have confirmation of this from Mathworks. I guess I can update an answer once this question is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Matlab does not offer support for modern .NET runtimes. According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/system-requirements-for-using-matlab-interface-to-net.html#:%7E:text=The%20MATLAB%20interface%20requires%20the,on%20Framework%202.0%20and%20above.) (already linked by @MiB_Coder) Matlab supports '.NET Framework Version 4.0 and above'. This means the `TargetFramework` property in your .csproj file must correspond to CRL (runtime) 4 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history).

This also means you can't use any C# code compiled for .NET Core, or .NET 5/6/7. This means that you are limited to C# <= 7.3 You should, however, be able to summon the class shown in the OP if it is compiled compiled using .NET Framework <= 4.8, or .NET Standard <= 2.0. I compiled using .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Standard 2.0 and both loaded into Matlab just fine.

A couple of comments:

1. Mathworks should update their support for newer and more universal .NET Runtimes. .NET Framework is a Windows-only version of .NET, but the fact that I was able to use code compiled against .NET Standard 2.0 tells me there is some hope that that version could be used on other OSs, but according to the documentation page only Windows is supported.
2. [According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version), .NET Standard 2.1 (which I don't currently have installed) supports C# <= 8.0, so if this works in Matlab interop, you will at least have some of the nice features that came in with 8.0 (`using` statements, nullable reference types, etc.).
3. To install CRL 4, you need to install a .NET SDK corresponding to this release. The developer packs and runtimes are available for download [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks).

Comment: looks like (in theory) net5+ is now supported, but I cannot get it to work. https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/language-interfaces.html